# Adding google font link to styled components createGlobalStyle

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The other css codes in **`GlobalStyle.js`** component are working except `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css.....` 
 I imported **`GlobalStyle.js`** in **`App.js`** same as the screenshot. Could you note why this isn't working?
[image]